# How can I add date field in workbench moderation form in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, workflows, workbench

I have a content type. I applied workflow for this content type of using the [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench), [Workbench moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation), [Workbench access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) module. When using I see arise a problem to add to my software that I want to add a date field at the `form#workbench-moderation-moderate-form`. Can someone guide me to add a date field at the `form#workbench-moderation-moderate-form`. 
[image]